# XCode Derived Data is being generated recursively because of script

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, recursion, ios-universal-framework

I try to create universal framework for Swift on XCode there I applied a aggregate framework script to "Build Phases -> Run Script".

It seems script is recursively in infinite loop and generate Derived Data recursively.

What I want is only to kill script so that derived data is generated no more. I clear and remove derived data, yet, it is generated again and allocate all the storage i have.

Here is a screenshot :

[xcode-swift-objective-c-recursion-ios-universal-framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhW9E.png)

Comment: So don't run the script.

Comment: I already did and i cannot find the way to stop it : /